# Migrate an ant script to Maven3

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm migrating a maven 1 project to maven 3. The job is almost done actually with a missing task, What I need is to get all dependency **names** from pom file and write them to a configuration file as one string, the job is done like below in the maven.xml, **check the last 5 lines where it writes the names to a file called wrapper.conf**.

How can I achive this with Maven3? Is there a maven plugin I can use for this or I need to use ant script within my pom.xml?

```
<goal name="service">
    <mkdir dir="${maven.build.dir}/grid" />
    <ant:copy todir="${maven.build.dir}/grid">
        <fileset dir="resources/javaservicewrapper" />
    </ant:copy>


    <j:forEach var="lib" items="${pom.artifacts}">
        <j:set var="dep" value="${lib.dependency}"/>
        <j:if test="${dep.getProperty('service.bundle')=='true'}">
            <ant:copy failonerror="true" todir="${maven.build.dir}/grid/lib">
                <fileset dir="${maven.repo.local}/${dep.groupId}/jars">
                    <include name="${dep.artifactId}-${dep.version}.${dep.type}"/>
                    <j:set var="SERVCP" value="../lib/${dep.artifactId}-${dep.version}.${dep.type}:${SERVCP}" />
                </fileset>
            </ant:copy>
        </j:if>
    </j:forEach>

    <attainGoal name="jar" />
    <ant:copy file="target/${maven.final.name}.jar" tofile="${maven.build.dir}/grid/lib/grid.jar" />

    <j:set var="SERVCP" value="${SERVCP}../lib/gridcache.jar" />

    <ant:copy todir="${maven.build.dir}/gridcache/conf" file="resources/javaservicewrapper/conf/wrapper.conf" overwrite="true">
        <filterset begintoken="@" endtoken="@">
            <filter token="service.classpath" value="${SERVCP}"/>
        </filterset>
    </ant:copy>

</goal>
```

**EDIT** : *The solution using build-classpath worked well but I had other problems specific to using Javaservicewrapper. So best solution I found was creating whole the script/config file by appassembler-maven-plugin and let maven-assembly plugin to copy it to the conf folder*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the need to create a JSW (wrapper.conf) the simplest solution would be to use the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which can create such files.

Comment: tnx I have the config file I just need to overwrite the wrapper.java.classpath.1 variable and add jar paths from my lib folder

Comment: still should I use this? or a better solution there you think?

Comment: I would suggest to use if you can, cause it makes the maven build simpler. Just take a [detailed look in the docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-jsw.html).

Comment: I use maven assembly plugin to create the release folder, so do you think i need to ditch the assemply plugin totally and start using appassembler plugin only to write a string to a conf file?

Comment: for example I already have a Java Service Wrapper install.sh script that I copied to my release package using assembly plugin, to my understanding the plugin you mentioned is creating these scripts if you don't have already am i correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can let the plugin generate that or you can maintain it yourself.

Comment: tnx, I create the conf file by appassembler-maven-plugin then later copy to my dir using assembly plugin.

Comment: Just a word of warning if you want to use Maven  appassembler-maven-plugin and Tanuki its stuck on version 3.2.3 to remain bsd compatable. To use later version of Tanuki you have to leave the maven way and its a pain. The current version Tanuki is on is 3.5.24 so you can see how far behind it is.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) goal of the Maven Depency Plugin. You can fast check the result on the command line:

> mvn dependency:build-classpath

You can change the path to the dependeny files using the '[prefix](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html#prefix)' (mdep.prefix) property

> mvn -Dmdep.prefix=myLibFolder dependency:build-classpath

You will find much more configuration parameters in the documentation, e.g. the [outputFile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html#outputFile) parameter ;-)

Comment: this plugin gives jar paths from .m2 rep, I need the jar paths from a lib folder that I exported my jars in the release package

Comment: @Spring Have a look at my update (use the `prefix/mdep.prefix` property to change the path).

Comment: thank you works! I also changed the seperators..but I need to automate this whenever I make a maven build and not run a mvn command with a lot of parameters, is that possible? and copy that string to an extarnal file

Comment: @Spring Yes of course, just define it in your pom.xml (have a look at the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency:build-classpath_mojo) example).

Comment: and I noticed this command makes a build when I run it, I only need to copy the file names and not make a build, since other existing plugins handle this I guess

Comment: @Spring When integrating the configuration in your pom.xml choose a [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase that is appropriate for you (maybe `process-sources`). Also have a look at my [How to read a Maven Plugin Documentation](http://frvabe.blogspot.de/2013/12/how-to-read-maven-plugin-documentation.html) blog post ;-)

Comment: things got more complex :) I use maven assembly plugin to create a zip file with a dynamic name in my target folder and the configuration file I want to write is in that package, so is that possible to access and write to that file by using dependency plugin? thanks!

Comment: I created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234302/maven-dependency-plugin-problems

Comment: thank you for your help but in my case I had to use the appassembler plugin

Comment: I'm fine if you found a solution for your problem ;-)