# Maven dependency plugin problems

Tags: java, maven

I use maven-assembly plugin to create a **zip** file for a release in my target folder. This package with **dynamic name** includes a configuration file;

```
/target/dailyrelease-4234.zip/cd/lib/conf/wrapper.conf
```

Now I also use maven-dependency plugin's build-classpath goal to output the dependencies as a string.

I want to write this output string to the configuration file created by the assembly plugin

I have 2 problems:

1- How can I access this conf file in the dynamic named zip?

2- I want to add some extra .jar paths to that string created by maven dependency plugin, but it only copies the names from local repository. is there a way to modify this output, or show dependency plugin to use another folder to pick the jar names and not from local repository?

Or even better make the creating dependency names task as a part of assembly-plugin so I dont need to access and modify that zip anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1 - It sounds like your mechanism for dynamically generating that number '4234' exists *outside* of Maven, and you're trying to figure out how to access that number from within Maven, correct?

If so, I suggest using the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) which generates a number which you can then access from within Maven via the `${buildNumber}` property.

2 - I suggest switching your callout from `dependency:build-classpath` to `dependency:list -DoutputFile=xyz.txt`.  The latter gives you a cleaner output of just groupId/artifactId/version which should be easy to edit.

Or better yet... Do the above, and simply use `<phase>` configuration to ensure `dependency:list` gets called before the assembly plugin runs (typically at the end of `package` phase), and ensure the resulting output file sits somewhere that the assembly plugin will pick it up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: tnx, the main problem is not the number but accessing a file inside a zip folder and edit one of its field by copying the generated classpath there